# Using summarise_each() with formula interface input

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to get `dplyr::summarise_each` to work with the formula interface of `lm`. In this trivial example, I am obtaining effect size estimates from a series of variables (x, y, z) based on a two and three level factor variable (group2, and group3).

```
set.seed(77)
example <- data.frame(group2 = factor(sample(1:2, 500, TRUE)),
                      group3 = factor(sample(1:3, 500, TRUE)),        
                      x = sample(1:100, 500, TRUE),
                      y = sample(1:100, 500, TRUE),
                      z = sample(1:100, 500, TRUE))
```

For group2, I can use `effsize:::cohen.d` to get the estimates for each variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(effsize)
cooksD <- summarise_each(example[3:5], 
                         funs(cohen.d(., f = example$group2, na.rm = TRUE)$estimate))
# cooksD
#        x     y    z
# 1 -0.08 -0.13 -0.01
```

However, to get r-squared for a 3 level object, I need to use `summary(lm())$r.squared`, which does not work:

```
rsq <- summarise_each(example[3:5], funs(summary(lm(. ~ group3, data = example))$r.squared))
# Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
#  invalid term in model formula
```

I know this is due to my use of "." in the `lm()` call, but I'm not sure how to pass the data vectors to `lm()`.  I've looked into `do()` but have so far been unsuccessful implementing that.

Comment: When I try to run your "successful" example I get "no applicable method for 'cohen.d' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: Sorry about that, code updated. Seems like the effsize package needs to be loaded for it to work properly.

Comment: The error can also be avoided by calling effsize:::cohen.d.default() instead of effsize:::cohen.d().  Forgot it was a generic with multiple methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be how dplyr replaces the variables in your function. Instead of looking like

```
lm(y~group3, example)
```

you get something like

```
lm(c(99L, 74L, 31L, 82L, ...) ~group3, example)
```

which (if the list is long enough), throws an error when trying to figure out the parameter name. Another method might be

```
summarise_each(example[3:5], 
    funs(summary(lm(RESP ~ group3, data = cbind(example, RESP=.)))$r.squared))
```

Here we bind the response column into the data.frame which isn't that efficient. I would probably avoid `summarize_each` in this case and to a more standard `lapply` over the symbols you wish to iterate over.

```
lapply(names(example)[3:5], function(r) {
    eval(substitute(summary(lm(r ~ group3, data = example))$r.squared, list(r=as.name(r))))
})
```

Comment: You could avoid copying all the example dataframe with this: `summarise_each(example[3:5],  funs(summary(lm(RESP ~ group3, data = cbind(example[ ,'group3', drop=FALSE], RESP=.)))$r.squared))`